# OpenCV Multithreading error [using Qt]

Tags: multithreading, qt, opencv

**Till now I have learnt one thing, there's something wrong I'm doing with OpenCV, Qt has no role in the error**

I'm trying to run two methods in different threads, but it gives me error:

> [xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
>   [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
>   [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
>   Blurring_Images: ../../src/xcb_io.c:178: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.

---

Here's my code:

```
void Dialog::blurImages(int b)
{
    QtConcurrent::run(this,&Dialog::homogenour_blur,b);
    QtConcurrent::run(this,&Dialog::gaussianBlur,b);
}

void Dialog::homogenour_blur(int b)
{
    cv::blur(img,img1,cv::Size(b,b));
    showImage("Homogenous Blur",img1);
}

void Dialog::gaussianBlur(int b)
{
    cv::GaussianBlur(img,img2,cv::Size(b,b),b);
    showImage("Gaussian Blur",img2);
}
```

whereas if i comment out one call(shown below), it runs fine

```
void Dialog::blurImages(int b)
{
    QtConcurrent::run(this,&Dialog::homogenour_blur,b);
    //QtConcurrent::run(this,&Dialog::gaussianBlur,b);
}
```

It's really annoying guys, please help !!

**EDIT:**
Instead of calling showImage(), I replaced it with the actial OpenCV call(see below):

```
void Dialog::homogenour_blur(int b)
{
    cv::blur(img,img1,cv::Size(b,b));
    //showImage("Homogenous Blur",img1);
    cv::imshow("Homogenous Blur",img1);
}

void Dialog::gaussianBlur(int b)
{
    cv::GaussianBlur(img,img2,cv::Size(b,b),b);
    //showImage("Gaussian Blur",img2);
    cv::imshow("Gaussian Blur",img2);
}
```

Now the error I get is:

> Original Image: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
>   Original Image: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.
>   Fatal Error: Accessed global static 'KGlobalSettings *s_self()' after destruction. Defined at ../../kdeui/kernel/kglobalsettings.cpp:190
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: the above code only runs with 1 call to the run method, so with the other one commented, I get 4

Comment: Are you doing what the error message suggests?  Namely, are you calling XInitThreads() in your application?

Comment: No
I don't even know what is XInitThreads()

Comment: Try calling XInitThreads() in "int main()" before you create your QApplication.  See the example at the bottom of this page: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq06-glimpsing.html.

Comment: that is for OpenGL, I don't have OpenGL, so I get XInitThreads() method was not declared in this scope

Comment: XInitThreads() is an X11 call, not an OpenGL call.

Comment: oh ya, got it,
but after calling that the app don't even start with one thread..

Answer (score 10):

To all concerned:

fix Jaydeep's problems

> [xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
>
> [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
>
> [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.

and

> error: ‘XInitThreads’ was not declared in this scope

by linking X11, including xlib, and calling XInitThreads.

Example for including xlib and calling XInitThreads:

```
// main.cpp
#include <thread> 
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main() {
   XInitThreads();
   // . . . 
}
```

Example for linking:

```
g++ main.cpp -o my_program -std=c++0x -pthread -lX11 /* -pthread if you're on Linux */
```

Of course, don't forget to link the other files that may be necessary to your application

Comment: This didn't fix my error, because I was writing from multiple threads. A way to solve this is to write the GUI calls from multiple threads into a queue, and process the queue from the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

imshow() method seems not thread safe. if you use python, it can be solved like this:

```html
self.img_lock = threading.Lock()

with self.img_lock:
  cv2.imshow()
  cv2.waitKey(1)
```